# Kubernetes kompose

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hi I am working on kubernetes using AWS EKS. I have a problem with kompose file when I am converting the docker-compose file into kompose file i had aproble with the volume mount point and as well when I run the command the kompose up it is asking the username which credential should i provide.

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    cms-db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        volumes:
            - "./shared/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=cms
            - MYSQL_USER=cms
            - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
        mem_limit: 1g
        env_file: config.env
    cms-xmr:
        image: xibosignage/xibo-xmr:release-0.7
        ports:
            - "9505:9505"
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 256m
        env_file: config.env
    cms-web:
        image: xibosignage/xibo-cms:release-1.8.10
        volumes:
            - "./shared/cms/custom:/var/www/cms/custom"
            - "./shared/backup:/var/www/backup"
            - "./shared/cms/web/theme/custom:/var/www/cms/web/theme/custom"
            - "./shared/cms/library:/var/www/cms/library"
            - "./shared/cms/web/userscripts:/var/www/cms/web/userscripts"
        restart: always
        links:
            - cms-db:mysql
            - cms-xmr:50001
        environment:
            - XMR_HOST=cms-xmr
        env_file: config.env
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        mem_limit: 1g


[root@my-ip xibo-docker-1.8.10]# kompose up
WARN Unsupported env_file key - ignoring
WARN Unsupported links key - ignoring
WARN Volume mount on the host "./shared/db" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "./shared/cms/custom" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "./shared/backup" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "./shared/cms/web/theme/custom" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "./shared/cms/library" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
WARN Volume mount on the host "./shared/cms/web/userscripts" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
INFO We are going to create Kubernetes Deployments, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application. If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'kubectl create -f' commands instead.

Please enter Username:
```

Answer (score 5):

The better way to apply your configuration to Kubernetes cluster is to convert it, check YAML files, adjust them if necessary and then apply them using `kubectl`.

I tested the conversion using `kompose v1.16.0` on Mac and I had to remove the `mem_limit` option from the `docker-compose.yml` file to complete it successfully.

```
$ mkdir export
$ kompose -v convert -f docker-compose.yml -o export
```

14 files will be created in the `export` directory.

Local paths are not supported - Persistent Volume Claim will be created instead (Warning will appear).
Persistent volume claims is `100Mi` by default. Edit the claim YAML files and increase the size if necessary.

Now your configuration can be deployed to Kubernetes cluster using:

```
kubectl create -f export/
```

Comment: can I know which credential should be provided when i am doing kompose up .             [root@ip- sample-kompose]# kompose up
INFO We are going to create Kubernetes Deployments, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application. If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'kubectl create -f' commands instead.

Please enter Username:

Comment: What error do you get if you enter some random data for username and password?

Comment: Please enter Username: admin
Please enter Password: password
INFO Deploying application in "default" namespace
FATA Error while deploying application: services is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create services in the namespace "default"

Comment: Looks like Kubernetes apiserver authorization error. Do you get any error when you run “kubectl get nodes”  ?

Comment: Nodes are running perfect. I am getting the running node with "kubectl get node"

Comment: Do you get any errors when you convert your file as I recommended in my answer and create deployment using kubectl? If it goes well, perhaps “kompose up” doesn’t work well with kubectl config.

Comment: I did not get any error when I convert a file. when I deploy one website using the kubectl perfectly deployed and running.

Comment: I could guess, it could be version incompatibility or a bug. Could you create an issue on the kompose github? https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues

Comment: Thanks. I need one more help like when I run  kubectl create -f export/  with the my file pods are running perfect but it is not expose external. can you please help with this.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
cms-db       ClusterIP   None             <none>        55555/TCP   4h
cms-web      ClusterIP   10.100.166.199   <none>        80/TCP      2h
cms-xmr      ClusterIP   10.100.129.140   <none>        9505/TCP    2h

Comment: It looks strange that your cms-db service doesn't have cluster IP assigned. Check the <kubectl describe svc cms-db> for errors.  There are three ways to expose services to outside: (1) Service type:NodePort, I don't see any services with node ports in your case, (2) Service type:LoadBalancer, it still use NodePort to get traffic from LB, (3) Ingress, To list them run <kubectl get ingress>,  then <kubectl describe ingress ingress-obj-name>. This actually means that you aren't exposing any of services to outside. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/

Comment: Services with ClusterIP: none (headless service) it's just several A records in the kubernetes dns service that points to service endpoints. This service doesn't create any iptables rules. If you request such service using command "host <service_name>" or "host service_name.namespace_name.svc.cluster.local",  it gives you several IP addresses of pods that match the service selector. IP addresses are returned in RoundRobin-ish order. Note: when you connect to such service you should use the port that Pod is exposing, because you literally connect to the pod directly.